# how to find and return the second to last value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to find last but one value in my DataFrame. The script below is properly looking for max value, however, I need to find max - 1 so if version is 4 I need to find version 3 in my DataFrame.

```
df.groupby('ID').max()['version']
```

In MySQL it can be done by using this query:

```
"SELECT *, max(version) - 1 FROM product GROUP BY ID;"
```

However I something like max() - 1 does not work in pandas. Can you please give me some hints on how to get desired value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` and compare by `1`, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('ID').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(1)]
```

If `versions` are integers numbers:

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('ID')['version'].transform('max').sub(1).eq(df['version'])]

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('ID')
```